# Input for numbers allows commas in Firefox

Tags: html, angular

I have my code and works perfectly in Chrome, I have an input number and it does not allow to write commas, but the problem is in Firefox, it allows me to write commas.

This is my code:

```
<input
    formControlName="quantity"
    type="number"
    matInput
    step="1"                                
 />
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Firefox bug - [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1398528) (and [backup link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210401015211/https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1398528111)).

You can use workarounds for this. Check this sources:

[1](https://medium.com/@theanasreza/angular-accept-number-only-directive-for-input-field-3aa533947fd9) ([backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20210401020905/https://medium.com/@theanasreza/angular-accept-number-only-directive-for-input-field-3aa533947fd9)) and [2](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-allow-only-numbers-or-alphanumeric-in-input-restrict-other-characters-using-keypress-event/) ([backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20210401021116/https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-allow-only-numbers-or-alphanumeric-in-input-restrict-other-characters-using-keypress-event/)).